# Is the single plurality system the same as the winner take all system?

Tags: voting-systems, plurality-voting-system, first-past-the-post

Is the single plurality system the same as the winner take all system? I've heard both terms, and they sound the same. Are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. More often, one would say the single member district plurality system. Another common term for it is the "[first past the post](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-past-the-post_voting)" system (mostly in British English). This sentence from the link uses versions of all three phrases:

> In the U.S., all states (except for Maine and Nebraska) and the
>   District of Columbia use a **winner-take-all** form of **simple
>   plurality**, **first-past-the-post** voting, to appoint the electors
>   of the Electoral College; Maine and Nebraska use a variation where the
>   electoral vote of each Congressional district is awarded by
>   first-past-the-post, in addition to the statewide winner taking two
>   votes. In winner-take-all, the presidential candidate gaining the
>   greatest number of votes wins all of the state's available electors,
>   regardless of the number or share of votes won, or the difference
>   separating the leading candidate and the first runner-up.